# Using replace function on Selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

Upon extracting context from webpage, I was left with a string "price: $30.00" which I stored as "x." all I needed was "30.00"(numbers only.) I tried replacing using x.replace(), but it was all in vain. I would appreciate if anyone can help me write the snippet.

I tried using storeEval, only to find that it had been removed. Replace was the only option I had and I tried using it only to enouter difficulties.

Answer (score 1):

```
// input
var x = "price: $30.00";

//Use regex
var numbers = x.match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/);

if (numbers) {
  var extractedNumber = numbers[0];
  console.log(extractedNumber);
} else {
  console.log("Numeric values not detected in the provided string.");
}
```

Comment: Looks interesting pal. Will definately give it a shot. Thanks alot.

Comment: The code worked great. Suppose the price was dynamic and we always have to extract it and store it as "x," how could we modify the snippet? I apologize for taking much of your time.

Comment: If your goal is to modify the snippet for consistent extraction and storage of the price as the variable "x" from a dynamic input string

`function extractPrice(inputString) {
    var numbers = inputString.match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/);
    if (numbers) {
        return numbers[0];
    } else {
        return null; // Return null if no numeric value
    }
}

// Example:
var dynamicInput = "price: $30.00";
var x = extractPrice(dynamicInput);

if (x !== null) {
    console.log("Extracted Price: $" + x);
} else {
    console.log("Numeric values not detected in the provided string.");
}`

Comment: Thanks alot. I wish there was a way that I could upvote for you..

Answer (score 0):

There is another (simpler) way:

```
var x = "price: $30.00";
var extractedNumber = x.split("$")[1];
```

Comment: Thanks alot @mate. I am sure that will work too. Is it possible to substitute "x" with the new extracted value? Or we have to create a new value? Maybe call it "new"

Comment: "x" is a variable name, you can call it as you wish.